# Computed Column in Entity Framework isn't updating Correctly?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a computed column in a View of SQL.  That computed column is called Quarter_Name.  This column tells me about the quarter of data it is from.

The following is the definition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [client_id]
  ,[auto_study_configuration_id]
  ,[study_type_id]
  ,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,[start_time_id],'1999-12-31')) AS VARCHAR) + 
   '-Q' + 
   CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,DATEADD(DAY,[start_time_id],'1999-12-31')) AS VARCHAR) AS quarter_name
  FROM [adeffx_system].[info].[mid_family_app_map]
```

This view returns the correct data.  The Quarter name is shown properly.

[image]

But when I run this view query in C# Entity Framework, this is what I get instead.

[image]

As you can see, everything makes sense, but the Quarter doesn't actually show the correct value.  Rather it duplicates the row and thinking that the Quarter is the same.

There is nothing big about the query.  Here it is.

```
var result = dbCall.OrderBy(x => x.client_id).Skip(model.iDisplayStart).Take(model.iDisplayLength).Select(MapDetailSummaryView).ToList();
```

I can't seem to figure out why Entity Framework has chosen to not calculate this column or maybe it shouldn't since the view is doing it instead.  Is this a bug within Entity Framework it self?

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM. It is not aware of the fact that you are selecting from a view and that this view contains a computed column. All it does - reads the data from the database based on the provided statement and maps columns to object properties. After your object has been instantiated it is completely on the .NET side (which is completely not aware of the fact that this property is calculated). If you want to you can make the property calculated in the getter for the property as well.

Comment: Results you have shown from the view represent the exact same query, with order by limit offset?